# Linq GroupJoin add default entries

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, linq-to-entities

```
var storeIds = repository.Get<Store>()
               .Select(s => s.Id)
               .ToList();

var storeReceipts = repository.Get<Receipt>()
        .Where(r => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(r.LogDate) == today)
        .GroupBy(r => r.StoreId)
        .Select(g => new { Id = g.Key, Sales = g.Sum(r => r.TotalPrice) })
        .GroupJoin(storeIds, x => x.Id, s => s, (x, s) => x ?? new { Id = s, Sales = 0 });
```

Basically I want the GroupJoin to add an entry to the sequence for any Store that doesn't have Receipt records.

My syntax above with the `??` doesn't compile (even if it did I am not sure its correct).

Comment: What's the type of `storeReceipts` that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: a sequence of anonymous type { Id, Sales } where if a store doesnt have any sales there is an entry with Id set but Sales = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to join the two tables, you may want to try this.

```
var storeSales = from s in repository.Get<Store>()
                 join r in repository.Get<Receipt>() on s.Id equals r.StoreId into g
                 select new {
                     StoreId = s.Id,
                     Sales = g.Sum(x => (decimal?)x.TotalPrice) ?? 0
                 };
```

It selects from the `Stores` first, so that you will get an entry for each store. It will next join the `Receipts` by matching store id into a group `g` that joins the two.

That allows the selection of your output shape, one item per store. In this case, the `Id` of the store as `StoreId`, and the sum of the `TotalPrice` values for each receipt as the `Sales` are selected.

If there were no receipts for a store, this sum will end up being 0.

Comment: When I tried this I got an exception: The cast to value type 'System.Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

Comment: @user380689   Is your `TotalPrice` field a nullable decimal? Could you post the code for the `Receipt` class please (added to your question).

Comment: No its not nullable:   public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }